# Formik form sending empty value

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have created a formik form, where a click on button will update the value in the input. It updates the value in the form but it sends an empty string in the backend.

```
     const [value, setValue] = useState('');
     <Input
        name="IpRange"
        value={value}
        onChange={({ target }) => setValue(target.value)}
      />
      <Button
        className="ip-button"
        onClick={() => setValue('0.0.0.0/0')}
      >
      </Button>
```